# 403- CSRF error while trying to login to a website using curl

Tags: curl, php-curl

I am trying to login to a website to fetch logs. I am getting 403 - CSRF token error.

I have tried many combination in curl script but nothing seems to be working.

```
<?php
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$url = "https URL";
$cookie= "/home/myfolder/cookies.txt";
$ua = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));

$token=exec("cat cookies.txt | grep 'csrftoken' |  sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' |  sed -e 's/csrftoken/^/g' |  cut -d '^' -f2");
echo "token ".$token;
file_put_contents('/home/myfolder/login_result.txt', $response);


$postinfo = "user=".$username."&pass=".$password."&CSRF_TOKEN=".$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
    file_put_contents('/home/myfolder/login_result.txt', $html);
if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I have also tried to run some curl commands from unix. I am getting some blockage error for XSS

```
-sh-4.1$ curl -k -v "httpds URL" -H "X-CSRFToken:uJipeKYyW3VMNbhocSzDE8xzv1p0t0cW" -b "csrftoken=uJipeKYyW3VMNbhocSzDE8xzv1p0t0cW" -d "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD"
OUTPUT:
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.intra.site.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 190.149.91.7... connected
* Connected to proxy.intra.bt.com (190.149.91.7) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to HTTPS_SITE
> CONNECT HTTPS_SITE HTTP/1.1
> Host: HTTPS_SITE
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> X-CSRFToken: uJipeKYyW3VMNbhocSzDE8xzv1p0t0cW
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=HTTPS_SITE,OU=ABC,O=ABCD,L=London,ST=London,C=GB
*       start date: Feb 06 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Feb 06 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*       common name: HTTPS_SITE
*       issuer: CN=ABC Secure Server CA - G4,O=ABCD,C=GB
> POST HTTPS_SITE
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: HTTPS_SITE
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: csrftoken=uJipeKYyW3VMNbhocSzDE8xzv1p0t0cW
> X-CSRFToken: uJipeKYyW3VMNbhocSzDE8xzv1p0t0cW
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
} [data not shown]
  0     0    0     0    0    39      0    201 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   245< HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
< Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 11:48:31 GMT
< Server: apache
< Content-Length: 85681
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.google-analytics.com *.doubleclick.net data:;img-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com *.doubleclick.net http://*.tile.osm.org *.tile.osm.org *.gstatic.com data:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;connect-src 'self';frame-src *;child-src 'self' data: *.vimeo.com;object-src 'none'
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Vary: Accept-Language,Cookie
< Content-Language: en-us
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< audited: False
< Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=._SERVER-4326ad1a201e9faba99117a749b1e53d; path=/
<
{ [data not shown]
100 85681  100 85681    0    39   232k    108 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  257k* Connection #0 to host proxy.intra.site.com left intact

* Closing connection #0
```

should be able to login but I am constantly getting 403 - CSRF error

Comment: you must show the actual site you're trying to log into, we can't figure out what you're doing wrong without checking how the login system on the website works.  (well it's obvious you're doing some encoding errors, if you are actually supposed to login with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format, then you need to use urlencode() or http_build_query(), but that's probably not why you're getting a CSRF error)

Comment: It's a company's internal URL.  Even if I share it you won't be able to open it as it works only on company's network.

Comment: perhaps hire someone to check it over teamviewer, nobody here can guess what you're missing or what you're doing wrong (except that you're not urlencoding, you're definitely doing that part wrong)